# Probability of Multiples

Tags: probability

simple question.

There exists a *t*% chance of success for every attempt made.  What is the probability of succeeding **at least** *n* times over the course of *i* iterations?

That is, a special coin has only a 20% chance of landing on heads.  What is the probability of flipping **at least** 2 heads (but possibly more) in any order over the course of 9 tosses?  (example)

Answer (score 0):

Let the probability of success be $p$, $0<p<1$. Let $X$ be a $\operatorname{Bin}(i,p)$ random variable. Then the quantity you're interested in is

$$\mathbb P(X\geqslant n)=\sum_{k=n}^i \binom ik p^k(1-p)^{i-k}. $$

In particular, when $p=\frac15$, $n=2$, and $i=9$, we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X\geqslant 2)&=\sum_{k=2}^9 \binom 9k \left(\frac15\right)^k\left(\frac45\right)^{9-k}\\&= 1 - \sum_{k=0}^2\binom 9k \left(\frac15\right)^k\left(\frac45\right)^{9-k}\\
&= 1 - \left(\binom 90\left(\frac15\right)^0\left(\frac45\right)^9 + \binom 91\left(\frac15\right)^1\left(\frac45\right)^8 \right)\\
&= 1 - \left(1\cdot1\cdot\left(\frac45\right)^9 +9\cdot\frac15\left(\frac45\right)^8 \right)\\
&= 1 - \left(\frac45\right)^8\left(\frac45 +\frac95 \right)\\
&= 1 - \frac{13\cdot4^8}{5^9}\\
&= \frac{1101157}{1953125}\\
&\approx 0.56379.
\end{align*}
 $$